# Lag between two sound "Mediaplayer" android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, lag

I want to play two sounds. I'm using this code but there's lag between the two sounds for about 2s. I want to play the second directly when the first sound is finished. How can I do that?

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.s83); 
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2){   
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.ss); 
        mp2.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 4.1 (v16) adds [MediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29) which was added to allow gapless playing as per the [feature list](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Gapless). Prior to that, there is always a small delay between `onCompletion` and starting another MediaPlayer due to buffering. Creating the second `MediaPlayer` before `onCompletion` might help as well (and would be required for using `setNextMediaPlayer` anyways).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make `mp2` a `MediaPlayer` class field and then use this code:

```
mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.ss); 
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.s83); 
mp.start();

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){   
        YourActivityClass.this.mp2.start();
    }
});
```

It will at least create the second `MediaPlayer` object and `prepare()` before the first sound is played, so you gain some time there.

Comment: thank you man , but MediaPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer it`s work better than your solution :)

Comment: @Alhazmy13: sure, but don't forget that you're now limiting your application to a minimum API of 16. But if you don't release your app on a market it might not matter.